# Mixed relationship in grails application

Tags: grails, grails-orm, relationship

I have a domain class which is called `Event`. `Event` has many registrations, which are users with account on site or people without it. I want registered user to be able to track their events, so `Event-User` relationship should be bidirectional (user is created by Spring Security). Still there are registrations which are not connected with user accounts. It's important since event is kind of a live competition with ranking, which is updated by event owner when event is over. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

this should work:

```
class User {
    static hasMany = [events:Event]
}


class Event {
    User user
    static constraints = {
       user(nullable:true)
    }
}
```

this way you can get the user from the event or all events for the user.

EDIT:

```
class User {
    static hasMany = [events:Event]
}


class Event {
    static hasMany = [users:User]
}
```

add Users to the Event with

```
event.addToUsers(user)
```

remove Users from Event with

```
event.removeFromUsers(user)
```

get all Users from Event

```
event.users
```

I'm not quite sure how you handle the not registered Users. Do you have no information about this users at all (no username etc ?)
I would suggest you add a flag in the User class "Boolean registered".
So you can create a User object for not registered Users also.

cheers manu

Comment: This is the part of which I know already. Btw: User-Event should be many-to-many. But how can I keep track in Event of users who are registered on my site and those who are not registered, but took part in the event (eg. signed up for the event where it took place). /My English is terrible/